# How to specify workspace to use in command line

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to write a Powershell script where I may need to checkout items into different workspaces. How can I specify in the `tf` command which workspace to use?

Comment: If you're already using PowerShell, why not just leverage the .NET API instead of messing around with `tf.exe`?

Comment: Your local file exists only in a single workspace.  Even though every command accepts `/workspace`, it is unnecessary here.  Simply specify the local paths.

Comment: @DanielMann, haven't looked into it yet, it's my 1st shot with tfs.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use the tfs workspace command and create a new 'temporary' workspace while your ps script executes. 
This only requires you to know the tfs path, you can then map to a local folder and only work with the files you need. At the end of the script you can delete the workspace.

Tfs workspace command

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se(v=vs.100).aspx